# Summarize Values in R Data Frame

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame in R that looks like this...

```
Time    Event
1       0
1       1
1       0
2       0
2       0
3       0
3       1
3       0
3       1
3       0
```

On this data frame, I want to get another data frame with a couple summary values. I want the original time, the count of rows with a time equal to or greater than the time in question, and the number of events that occurred at that time.

Example output:

```
Time    Eligible    Event
1       10          1
2        7          0
3        5          2
```

I've tried using the `match`, `by`, and `table` functions to accomplish this, but I can't make anything stick. I could do a double `for` loop... but there's got to be a better way.

How can I do this? I'd like to do it in base R, not using `plyr` or some other library...

Comment: Can you describe how you got the Eligible column

Comment: Yes... it's the number of rows with a time value equal to or greater than the time in question. So there's 10 rows with a time equal to or greater than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only `base R`, we can loop the unique "Time" using `lapply`, get the summary statistics based on the conditions described.

```
 res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$Time), function(x) 
          data.frame(Time=x, Eligible=sum(x<=df$Time),
                Event=sum(df$Event[df$Time %in%x]))))

 res
 #  Time Eligible Event
 #1    1       10     1
 #2    2        7     0
 #3    3        5     2
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(Time = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
 ), Event = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("Time", 
"Event"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Getting close... this is working for the eligibility, but I'm getting all 0s for the events...

Comment: @JohnChrysostom  Based on your dataset and expected result, I get the same

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tapply` to the same effect

```
newData <- data.frame(
    Eligible = tapply(myData$Event,myData$Time,length),
    Events = tapply(myData$Event,myData$Time,sum))
```

If you have multiple summaries, you can `lapply` over the fields of your data.frame.

Comment: Don't want to use `plyr`, as I specified, and `tapply` doesn't work on dataframes...

Comment: @JohnChrysostom nothing in his answer suggests you use `plyr`

Comment: `tapply` doesn't work on a whole data frame, but it can be used on one column as a grouper and another column to summarize.

Comment: Thanks for updating this to not suggest `plyr` and also editing the function. This gets closer to the answer requested, but still isn't right. I've already accepted the one above. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No worries. You can't go wrong with an answer from @akrun

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a little bit more interpretable:

```
countEligible <- function(x, Time) {

  sum(x <= Time)

}

dat1 <- data.frame(Time = unique(dat$Time), Eligible = unique(sapply(dat$Time, function(x) countEligible(x, dat$Time))))

dat2 <- data.frame(Time = unique(dat$Time), Event = tapply(dat$Event, dat$Time, sum))

merge(dat1, dat2)

> merge(dat1, dat2)
  Time Eligible Event
1    1       10     1
2    2        7     0
3    3        5     2
```